# How I can serialize form and send JSON request Ajax in Razor Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have form with list checkbox's and three input text and I wanna send it's 
on server in format json and accept it. How I can do it? 
I tried to do so

```
$(function () {
    $('#show').click(function () {
        var ser = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(ser),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: successFunc
        });
    });
});
function successFunc(data, status) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your code didn't work is because you need to [add a header for the Request Verification token to the AJAX request](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification#ajax-post-requests) when you post data as JSON:

```
$(function(){
    $(':submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    });
});
```

If you don't do this, you get a 400 Bad Request result, which is why your code fails.

The currently accepted answer appears to work because it does NOT post JSON (which according to your question is the requirement). Values are posted as standard URL-encoded name/value pairs instead.

If you actually want to post JSON, you need to stringify the form values.

Comment: what mean ':'  before  'submit' ?

Comment: That's just a css selector. It will match `<input type="submit">`. Just replace it with your selector: `#show`

Comment: Thanks, but i not understood what i must do that accept  this json?

Comment: Normally, you would only post JSON to a service that expects JSON and can deal with it, like a Web API controller. You wouldn't usually post JSON to a Razor Page.